# OpenCV : How to find the center of mass/centroid for motion information

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing, motion-detection, centroid

The thing is I am unable to implement the center of mass with the existing code, which image object to use etc after the detected object is bounded by the rectangle so that I may get the trajectory of the path.
    I am using `Opencv2.3` .I found out there are 2 methods - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542121/finding-an-images-contours-centroid) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074202/opencv-2-centroid) talk about the usage of moments. And the other method is to use the information of the bounding box [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942742/opencv-c-usage-of-cvmoments). The method of moments requires image thresholding. However, when using SURF the image is in gray scale. So, on passing a gray image for thresholding displays a white image! Now, I am having a tough time in understanding how I should calculate the centroid using the code below (esp what should I use instead of `points[i].x` since I am using

```
obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt )
```

where in my case `numPoints=good_matches.size()`, denoting the number of feature points)  as mentioned in the documentation. If anyone can put up an implementation of how to use SURF with centroid then it will be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat object = imread( "object.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

    if( !object.data )
    {
        std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 500;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

    detector.detect( object, kp_object );

    //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat des_object;

    extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("Good Matches");

    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    //Get the corners from the object
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
    obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
    obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

    char key = 'a';
    int framecount = 0;
    while (key != 27)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        if (framecount < 5)
        {
            framecount++;
            continue;
        }

        Mat des_image, img_matches;
        std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
        std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
        std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
        std::vector<Point2f> obj;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
        Mat H;
        Mat image;

        cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        detector.detect( image, kp_image );
        extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );

        matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

        for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
        {
            if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][4].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
            {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
            }
        }

        //Draw only "good" matches
        drawMatches( object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

        if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
            {
                //Get the keypoints from the good matches
                obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
                scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
            }

            H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

            perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

            //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
        }

        //Show detected matches
        imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );

        key = waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so, you already got your pointlists,

```
obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
```

i think, it's perfectly valid, to calc the centroid based on that, no further image processing nessecary.

there's 2 methods, the 'center of mass' way, that's just the mean position of all points, like this:

```
Point2f cen(0,0);
for ( size_t i=0; i<scene.size(); i++ )
{
    cen.x += scene[i].x;
    cen.y += scene[i].y;
}
cen.x /= scene.size(); 
cen.y /= scene.size();
```

and the 'center of bbox' way

```
Point2f pmin(1000000,1000000);
Point2f pmax(0,0);
for ( size_t i=0; i<scene.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( scene[i].x < pmin.x ) pmin.x = scene[i].x;
    if ( scene[i].y < pmin.y ) pmin.y = scene[i].y;
    if ( scene[i].x > pmax.x ) pmax.x = scene[i].x;
    if ( scene[i].y > pmax.y ) pmax.y = scene[i].y;
}
Point2f cen( (pmax.x-pmin.x)/2,  (pmax.y-pmin.y)/2);
```

note, that the results will be different ! they're only the same for circles & squares, point symmetric objects

```
// now draw a circle around the centroid:
cv::circle( img, cen, 10, Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );

// and a line connecting the query and train points:
cv::line( img, scene[i], obj[i], Scalar(255,0,0), 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you.Following questions/issues on implementing your answer.Plz pardon me if it appears to be trivial as my knowledge is highly limited at the beginner level.(A)Where do I put your codes?Is it outside last if loop or under for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ ).(B)In the first method,should not there be an array subscript with  cen += scene[i]; since it throws error.(C)Is there a way to record the measured & target position or draw a line indicating the motion of the detected object since tracking operation is also being performed?(D)How do I display values using second method?

Comment: (A) yes, inside the good_matches loop  (B) ? yea sloppy code from me there, my bad  (C) opencv has a line( img,from,to,color,thickness) function  (D) you could draw a small  circle(img,center,radius,color) but please look into the documentation for the exact args there

Comment: I could not find the syntax in C++ style for displaying the measured and target position.Could you kindly append your code with it?Also,for (B) will it be cen[i]+=scene[i]; cen[0] /= scene.size(); 
cen[1] /= scene.size(); and all this goes inside the good_matches loop but after the lines are drawn between the mapped objects?